# Copy songs to iPhone

Tags: itunes

I am very new to Ubuntu (& iPhone too). Installed Ubuntu upon best review from users and i have tried GTKpod, libimobile, banshee, Rhythmbox......a chap explaining to install iTunes 32 bit installation in Ubuntu with Wine etc. Why not a iTunes app for Ubuntu? Is there no working way to sync songs with iPhone?

Comment: I have only gotten it to work by running iTunes in a Windows virtual machine.

Comment: "Why not a iTunes app for Ubuntu?" You would need to ask Apple to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Wammu from the software center of Ubuntu. It used to work with my Nokia Lumia which works similar way like the iPhone when it comes to exchange files between Phone/PC.
If the program is not working install gammu too and try again.
Restart may be required afret the installation.